# Compute $\pi_1(S^1 \times (0,\infty))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Compute  $\pi_1(S^1 \times (0,\infty))$

My attempt : By uisng the theorem $\pi_1( X\times Y) $ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y)$ if  $X$ and $Y$ are connected

we have  $\pi_1(S^1 \times (0,\infty))=\pi_1(S^1) \times \pi_1(0, \infty)$

Since $(0,\infty)$ is contractible so $\pi_1(0, \infty)=0$ and $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$

$\implies  \pi_1(S^1 \times (0,\infty))=\pi_1(S^1) \times \pi_1(0, \infty)=\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}=0$

Therefore  $\pi_1(S^1 \times (0,\infty))=0$

Is it true ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z \times \{0\}\neq 0$ nor $\{0\}$, even set-theoretically.

Comment: What you probably meant was $\Bbb Z \times 0  = \Bbb Z$, in which case you're fine...almost. What's actually true is that the two groups are isomorphic (possibly by the isomorphism that sends $1$ to $-1$, for instance, unless you show otherwise). People usually write "=", but it's worth remembering that there's a hidden isomorphism in there.

Comment: More directly, you can use the fact that the contractibility of $(0, \infty)$ implies that $S^1 \times (0, \infty)$ and $S^1$ are homotopy-equivalent (and unravelling the definition gives you an explicit isomorphism between their fundamental groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close. You made one mistake. In the category of groups, $A \times 0 \simeq 0$ does not hold. In fact, for groups, $0 = 1$, so $A \times 0 \simeq A \times 1 \simeq A$.

So $\mathbb{Z} \times 0 \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.